# Максимальный размер словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Обращаюсь к серверу с пустой маской на 10 значений, на самом сервере такому условию подходят 16304 слова, однако, если я захочу их сохранить в переменную (или вывести), питон ограничит 500 значениями, можно как-то обойти данное ограничение?

```
import requests as rq
lst = "----------"
params = {"mask": lst}
responce = rq.get("https://poncy.ru/crossword/crossword-solve.jsn?", params=params)
a =(responce.json()["words"])
len(a)
```

Comment: Python ничего не ограничивает. Это сайт отдал только 500 слов. Там же есть кнопка "Загрузить ещё", которая дёргает другой URL `https://poncy.ru/crossword/next-result-page.json?mask=----------&page=1`. Но если попытаться грузить оставшиеся слова (сайт отдаёт на каждой странице не более 500 слов) увеличивая номер страницы, то сайт вас быстро заблокирует с формулировкой `"К сожалению - с вашего IP адреса обнаружена подозрительная активность, поэтому доступ на сайт временно заблокирован."`.

Comment: Спасибо! Так и думал, не знаю почему написал, что питон ограничивает, ведь явно можно и больше сохранять, сформулировал неверно.

Comment: GrAnd, можно поинтересоваться как вы обращаетесь к кнопке "загрузить еще"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так загружает:

```
import requests as rq
import time

lst = "----------"
params = {"mask": lst}
responce = rq.get("https://poncy.ru/crossword/crossword-solve.jsn", params=params)

data = responce.json()
words = data["words"]
count = int(data["count"])

params["page"] = 0
while len(words) < count:
    params["page"] += 1
    time.sleep(1.1) # задержка между запросами чтобы сайт не заблокировал по IP
    responce = rq.get("https://poncy.ru/crossword/next-result-page.json", params=params)
    words.extend(responce.json()["words"])
print(len(words)) # 16304
```

Без задержки между запросами можете получить блок за *"DoS-атаку"*. :)
Чего он там считает и как, и какую минимальную задержку (или ещё чего) надо поставить, чтобы с гарантией, я не знаю. Но с задержкой 0.1 секунды он заблокировал IP уже на 17-ом запросе, с задержкой 0.3 или 0.5 - на 25-27-ом. *(благо для экспериментов, что на Google Colab можно менять виртуальные машины вместе с IP как перчатки)*
В общем на ваш страх и риск, сайт с большим вниманием относится к автоматизированным запросам.

Comment: Вау, круто! Меня блокнули, ахах, не могу закинуть даже один простенький запрос, но первый раз прошло) спасибо за развернутый комментарий и уточнение насчет IP и коллаба!